# Python - How can I check if a CSV file has a comma or a semicolon as a separator?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I have a bunch of CSV files that I would like to read with Python Pandas. Some of them have a comma as a delimiter, hence I use the following command to read them:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_with_commas.csv')
```

However I have others CSVs that have a semicolon as a delimiter. Hence, since the default separator is the comma, I now need to specify it and therefore use the following command:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv('file_with_semicolons.csv', sep=';')
```

I would like to write a piece of code that recognises if the CSV file has a comma or a semicolon as a delimiter (before I read it) so that I do not have to change the code every time. How can this be done?

**Note**: I have checked this similar question on Stack Overflow but it is helpless since it is applicable to R, rather than Python.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Say that you would like to read an arbitrary CSV, named `input.csv`, and you do not know whether the separator is a comma or a semicolon.

You could open your file using the `csv` module. The `Sniffer` class is then used to deduce its format, like in the following code:

```py
import csv
with open(input.csv, newline='') as csvfile:
    dialect = csv.Sniffer().sniff(csvfile.read())
```

For this module, the `dialect` class is a container class whose attributes contain information for how to handle delimiters (among other things like doublequotes, whitespaces, etc). You can check the `delimiter` attribute by using the following code:

```py
print(dialect.delimiter)
# This will be either a comma or a semicolon, depending on what the input is
```

Therefore, in order to do a smart CSV reading, you could use something like the following:

```py
if dialect.delimiter == ',':
    df = pd.read_csv(input.csv)            # Import the csv with a comma as the separator
elif dialect.delimiter == ';':
    df = pd.read_csv(input.csv, sep=';')   # Import the csv with a semicolon as the separator
```

More information can be found [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html#csv.Sniffer).

Answer (score 3):

Use `sep=None`

```
df = pd.read_csv('some_file.csv', sep=None)
```

[From the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

> **sep str, default ‘,’**
>
> Delimiter to use. **If sep is None, the C engine cannot automatically detect the separator, but the Python parsing engine can,
> meaning the latter will be used and automatically detect the separator
> by Python’s builtin sniffer tool, csv.Sniffer.** In addition,
> separators longer than 1 character and different from '\s+' will be
> interpreted as regular expressions and will also force the use of the
> Python parsing engine. Note that regex delimiters are prone to
> ignoring quoted data. Regex example: '\r\t'

.

Comment: I found it helpful to add `engine="python"` as an argument to suppress a warning